# Deleting and reorganising an array of markers on a Leaflet Map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I wonder if someone might be able to help.

I have a map displayed on a web page and allow the user to add markers via a Geocoder or by clicking the map. The markers are added as layers as I wish to manipulate them independently. Currently, I allow up to 3 markers to be added. I would like to have the functionality to remove a marker by clicking on it.

I have used an array to hold the markers because I want to be able to adjust the maximum number of allowed markers at any point. Within a for-loop I have attached a listener to each marker in the array and if it is clicked, I remove it from the map and set its co-ordinates to null. If it is not the last marker in the array, I shuffle the others up to fill the gap.

The first time I click a marker, after adding three markers, it correctly identifies the marker I wish to delete and does everything I wish including the shuffle. When I try and click to remove another marker, though, I run into a problem in that it either doesn't remove the marker I click or it removes a marker I did not click, again it is only on the subsequent attempted deletes after one successful delete.

I think the problem is either I cannot have a listener inside a for loop or I am not appreciating the way adding and removing layers to a map work. The code is below and if anyone could offer some suggestions or alternative ways to approach my objective I would appreciate it.

```
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfLocationsAllowed; i++){
    let click = 0;
    mapMarkers[i].on('click', function (event) {

      // Remove the marker from the map
      map.removeLayer(mapMarkers[i]);

      // Clear the LatLng for the marker
      mapMarkers[i].setLatLng(null);

      // decrement the counter for the number of locations chosen
      locationsChosen -= 1;
      
      // If the location deleted was not the last one then shuffle those after it up one to fill the blank space
      // if it was the last one then no shuffle required and last one already null
      if (i != (numberOfLocationsAllowed - 1) ) {
        // Iterate through the array from the location slot deleted to the end
        for (let x = i; x < (numberOfLocationsAllowed - 1); x++) {
          // Set the current one to the one after it
          mapMarkers[x] = mapMarkers[x + 1];
        }
      }
      // Clear the last allowable location in the array as after any delete, the last location will, post-shuffle,
      // always be empty
      mapMarkers[numberOfLocationsAllowed - 1] = L.marker([
                                                                ,
                                                              ], {
                                                                icon: smartIcon,
                                                                draggable: true,
                                                                autoPan: true,
                                                              });

          };

        // Now set the click flag to indicate a marker was clicked so that we break
        // out of the loop as only one marker will ever be clicked at any one time
        click = 1;
      });

      // If a marker was clicked, it should have been dealt with in the click function and
      // the loop should be terminated as only one marker can be clicked at a time
      if (click == 1){
        click = 0;
        break;
      }

  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extended one of my [examples](https://tomik23.github.io/leaflet-examples/#18.add-move-and-delete-marker) with a condition so that I could only add a maximum of 3 markers.
I hope it will help.

```js
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/**
 * add move and delete marker
 */

let allMarkers = [];

// config map
let config = {
  minZoom: 7,
  maxZoom: 18,
};
// magnification with which the map will start
const zoom = 18;
// co-ordinates
const lat = 52.22977;
const lng = 21.01178;

// calling map
const map = L.map("map", config).setView([lat, lng], zoom);

// Used to load and display tile layers on the map
// Most tile servers require attribution, which you can set under `Layer`
L.tileLayer("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
}).addTo(map);

// add marker on click
map.on("click", addMarker);

function addMarker(e) {
  // Add marker to map at click location
  const markerPlace = document.querySelector(".marker-position");
  markerPlace.textContent = `new marker: ${e.latlng.lat}, ${e.latlng.lng}`;



  const marker = new L.marker(e.latlng, {
    draggable: true,
  }).bindPopup(buttonRemove);


  if (allMarkers.length >= 3) return;

  allMarkers.push(allMarkers.length + 1)

  marker.addTo(map)

  // event remove marker
  marker.on("popupopen", removeMarker);

  // event draged marker
  marker.on("dragend", dragedMaker);
}

const buttonRemove =
  '<button type="button" class="remove">delete marker </button>';

const markerPlace = document.querySelector(".marker-position");

// remove marker
function removeMarker() {
  const marker = this;
  const btn = document.querySelector(".remove");
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    markerPlace.textContent = "goodbye marker ";
    map.removeLayer(marker);
  });
  allMarkers.pop();
}

// draged
function dragedMaker() {
  markerPlace.textContent = `change position: ${this.getLatLng().lat}, ${
    this.getLatLng().lng
  }`;
}
```

```css
*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body,
html,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji";
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.marker-position {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div class="marker-position">click on the map, move the marker, click on the marker</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: This has been really helpful, thanks.